# Simple HTML DOM Parser - find class with random number

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrap data from one websites. I stuck on ratings. 
They have something like this:

```
<div class="rating-static rating-10 margin-top-none margin-bottom-sm"></div>
<div class="rating-static rating-13 margin-top-none margin-bottom-sm"></div>
<div class="rating-static rating-46 margin-top-none margin-bottom-sm"></div>
```

Where `rating-10` is actually one star, `rating-13` two stars in my case, `rating-46` will be five stars in my script.

Rating range can be from 0-50.

My plan is to create `switch` and if I get class range from 1-10 I will know how that is one star, from 11-20 two stars and so on.

Any idea, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually I didn't try nothing because I don't have idea. I'm really stuck. I can grab that element for example by 'rating-static' class but how I can figure what is rating? I'm totally confused. @KhorneHoly 

Do you have any suggestion? I will try immediately.

Comment: @PottaG try below code it will give you expected output

Comment: @PottaG I wrote an answer, have a look at it. I didn't test it, but it should work and give you the basic idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$data = '<div class="rating-static rating-10 margin-top-none margin-bottom-sm"></div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
$div_style = $div->getAttribute('class');
$final_data = explode(" ",$div_style);
echo $final_data[1];
?>
```

this will give you expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I had an similiar project, this should be the way to do it if you want to parse the whole HTML site

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); // The HTML Source of the website

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node){

    if($node->getAttribute("class") == "rating-static"){ 

        $array = explode(" ", $node->getAttribute("class"));
        $ratingArray = explode("-", $array[1]); // $array[1] is rating-10

        //$ratingArray[1] would be 10
        // do whatever you like with the information
    }
}
```

It could be that you must change the `if` part to an `strpos` check, I haven't tested this script, but I think that `getAttribute("class")` returns all classes. This would be the if statement then

```
if(strpos($node->getAttribute("class"), "rating-static") !== false)
```

Comment: Thank you, but Keval answer was first and I used this 
getAttribute('class')

Thank you both of us guys.

Answer (score 0):

FYI try using [Querypath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-querypath/) for future parsing needs. Its just a wrapper around PHP DOM parser and works really really well.